# Express 4.0 Failed to Look up view in "/views" directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, express-4

I am working with Express 4.0 and Express3-handlebars libraries for NodeJS.

Here is the configuration

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views/'));
app.engine('hbs', hbs({defaultLayout: 'main', extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

The contact.html is in the views directory

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.render("contact");
});
```

This is the error i get :

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "contact" in views directory "/Users/max23/Desktop/Node/views/"
```

I spent over an hour trying to fix it to no avail. What is Wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Handlebars templating library, so your views should have .hbs extension, not .html. Change contact.html to contact.hbs and do that to all of your templates. Also, change this line

```
app.engine('hbs', hbs({defaultLayout: 'main.hbs', extname: '.hbs'}));
```

Comment: notice how the name of the engine and the extension have to be the same... noticed on another thread too... confused me for a while and I can't be the only one (it looks like just an identifier!)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using *hbs* as your view system, you should use the .hbs extension for your view files. It fails to lookup the view because its an HTML, and its looking for *contact.hbs*

I personally dont have much experience with the handlebars library, but I suggest you change the contact.html extension to .hbs and try again

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong in the setting views path.
Try changing the line

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views/'));
```

by

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));
```

If not solved, show your folder structure.